# Нахождение всех циклов в графе

Tags: графы, алгоритм, c++

Есть граф, представленный списком в файле, где `n` - количество вершин. Необходимо найти все циклы в графе. С кода у меня пока что есть только чтение графа, чтобы было понятнее что к чему.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

#define FOR(i,a,b) for (int i(a), __N(b); i < __N; ++i)

typedef vector<int> VI;
typedef vector<VI> VVI;

set<VI> res;

void R(){}

int main(int argc, char *args){

    // переопределение потоков
    freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("out.txt", "w", stdout);

    // чтение графа
    int n, a, b;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    VVI G(n);
    res = set<VI>();
    while (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) != -1){
        G[a].push_back(b);
        G[b].push_back(a);
    }

    // обработка графа

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Совет: уточните формулировку

К сожалению, без точной формулировки задачи ответить на ваш вопрос очень сложно. Для начала, что вы ищете? Простые циклы? Элементы циклического пространства? Обычные циклы? Понимаете ли вы, что для полного графа с `n` вершинами размер ответа в любой из вышеперечисленных задач не меньше `n!`? Такой огромный размер ответа (а, значит, и время работы) говорит о том, что с практической точки зрения задача мало полезна (для полного графа с 14 вершинами это порядка 100 миллиардов циклов). Поэтому я крайне рекомендую уточнить постановку/необходимость задачи.

#### Если всё же нужно решить именно эту задачу

Например, с помощью алгоритмов поиска [MST](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) можно найти все фундаментальные циклы графа. Каждый цикл в графе является линейной комбинацией (коэффициенты берутся 0 или 1, сложение — исключающее или циклов) фундаментальных циклов, поэтому, перебрав эти комбинации, и взяв только нужные вам (только связные, или только простые), вы найдёте ответ. Это далеко не самый оптимальный алгоритм (`O(2^m)`, где `m` — число рёбер), и я не сомневаюсь, что его можно немного улучшить, если уточнить постановку задачи.

Answer (score -2):

Здесь нужно создать следующие классы:

```
struct TGraphConnection : public TObject{
    TPoint;   // содержит номера точек, которые он соединяет
};

class TGraphConnectionList : public TObjectList{ // содержит список всех соединений
};

class TGraphKnot : public TObjectList{
    __property int KnotNo...; // порядковый номер узла
    __property TGraphConnection *Connection[int Index]...;
};

// класс описания узла
// содержит набор TGraphConnection структур, которые примыкают к этому узлу
class TGraphKnotList : public TObjectList{
    __property TGraphKnot *Knot[int Index]...;
};
// содержит список TGraphKnotList - всех узлов графа
```

И главный класс, ответственный за все предыдущие:

```
class TGraph{
    private:
    TGraphConnectionList *Connections;
    TGraphKnotList * Knots;

    public:
    // здесь конструктор-деструктор
    void __fastcall Calc(); // сама функция подсчета каких-то там циклов
};
```

Вот где-то так всё может выглядеть...

Алгоритм подсчета циклов легко можно найти в инете...)))